# Composer Conflict

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a private repository (`my/private-repo`) that has 2 tags at the same commit.

```
v1.0.0-RC
v1.0.0
```

I have a project with composer.json as follows

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3.11",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
    "my/private-repo": "1.0.0-RC"
  },
```

Running `composer update` works fine. If I removed the `-RC` from the last line (so its `"my/private-repo": "1.0.0"` and run `composer update` I get the following result

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires my/private-repo 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by my/private-repo[v1.0].
    - my/private-repo v1.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle 4.2.* -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.2.0, ..., v4.2.12] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I have tried with `--with-all-dependencies` and get the same response. Can anyone help me understand why its failing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason for the error. There was another tag within the `my/private-repo` of `v1.0` which was against a commit from a previous version. It seems that composer picks up `v1.0` even though I specified `1.0.0`.

Removing the previous tag fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a look down below in your `composer.json` - `Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"` is a good hint that you've configured Flex to load Symfony v4.4 for your project. According to the given error message, `my/private-repo` explicitly requires v4.2.

Either downgrade the Symfony version in your `composer.json` and run `composer update` afterwards, or check why that private package is not compatible with any later version of Symfony

Comment: Both branches/tags have the same composer.json in the private repo. The following is at the bottom - `"extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "4.4.*"
    }
  }`

Comment: Yeah - you ether need to remove that from your application, or update the package to use a more recent version of Symfony. Having that `extra` session in any of the private packages does not have any effect, as this is only handled in the root package